# If isolated points are not dense, then removing their closure leaves a space without isolated points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I have to show that for a complete metric space $Z$, if $Z\ne\overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\right)}$, then $\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\setminus\overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\right)}\right)=\emptyset$. Here $\operatorname{iso}(Z)$ is the set of isolated points of $Z$.

I'm having trouble proving this because I thought that if we remove the isolation points of a metric space $Z$, then the set of isolation points of $Z\setminus\overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\right)}$ would automatically be empty, regardless of if $Z$ is complete and that $Z\ne\overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\right)}$.

Is there a metric space Z such that when we remove the requirement of completeness or that $Z\ne\overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\right)}$, then $\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\setminus\overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\right)}\right)\ne\emptyset$?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{iso}(Z)$?

Comment: @PotatoHead47 it is the set of isolated points of $Z$.

Comment: To see what's going on, consider the space $\{0\}\cup \{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$. If you remove all isolated points, you are left with $\{0\}$, which __becomes__ an isolated point. This is why in this problem one removes the closure.  The assumption $Z\ne\overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(Z\right)}$ is not important; if it doesn't hold, then the complement is just empty space, which doesn't have isolated points either.

Comment: I found an example of a topological space which satisfies the condition you want, I couldn't come up with a metric space that does though.
Consider the $X$={a,b,c} equipped with the topology T={$\phi$, {a},{b}, {a,b}, {b,c}, {a,b,c}}
$\operatorname{iso}(X)$ ={a,b}=$ \overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(X\right)}$ 
then $c \in$ $\operatorname{iso}\left(X\setminus\overline{\operatorname{iso}\left(X\right)}\right)$